# Programmatically change FileChooserDialog to list directories first with Python 3.4 and Gtk3?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm new to UI developement with Gtk and ran into something I didn't expect.  The FileChooser automatically sorts by name, regardless to if it's a file or directory.  I like having directories listed first, and people are used to/expect it.

Is there some way I can get FileChooser to behave this way?

EDIT:
In most of the major visual file managers, it is the default behavior to list the directories before the files.  These links show what people typically see in their file managers:
[konqueror](http://agateau.com/2010/obsessed-with-details-file-dialog-audio-preview/kfileaudiopreview-before.png), [nautilus](http://blogs.gnome.org/cneumair/files/2008/02/screenshot-compact-icons.png), [thunar](http://almostconnecticut.net/linuxismylife/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/foresight_03.png), [windows](https://earthsci.stanford.edu/computing/hosting/access/images/windowsexplorerwwwfolder.png), [osx](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2013/04/total-finder.jpg) and this is what I'm seeing with [my Gtk FileChooser](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1214223085603).  Is there a way I can get it to look like the rest of the file managers by default, using code?

EDIT2, the code I open it with:

```
dialog=Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Select a file",self,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,(
            Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
            Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
response=dialog.run()
```

Comment: Don't. Just because _you_ are used to it being that way doesn't mean _I_ am, too. File a bug and let them fix it.

Comment: @Rawing Thank you for your comment, it convinced me I needed to add more detail to my question.  I have revised it a bit and included some examples showing that this is default behavior for most file managers.  I'm not trying to force the users to share my preferred experience, I'm trying to change the experience to what the majority of users are already used to.

Comment: Another idea is to create your own file chooser. Yes! it'll take time but you'll get what you want. After all is a listview listing first folder names and files at the end. Not that hard as it sounds.

Comment: The full documentation for the gtk file chooser is here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html
I didn't notice anything about folder first, but I've also never noticed that my gtk-driven desktop ever listed files first either. Are you willing to share your source lines?

Comment: In addition to the GtkFileChooserDialog docs there's https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html which has methods shared by the other file choosers in GTK+ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Fabby and ThorSummoner's comments, I've stumbled across the closest solution.  Using GSettings, I can change the FileChooser settings from the app, though only globally. This should be okay in this case, since the user will likely prefer to have the same experience with all Gtk based FileChoosers on their system.

```
from gi.repository import Gio

setting = Gio.Settings.new("org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser")
setting.set_boolean("sort-directories-first", True)
```

As expected, setting it to False will only sort by the names and not group the directories together.

The setting can also be bound to a control with [Gio.Settings.bind()](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gio-2.0/classes/Settings.html#Gio.Settings.bind)

I've opted for a setting switch that the user will be able to set for their preference.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing [snippet below] the gtk file chooser always lists folders before files.

**Example Adapted from:** https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html
**Python docs at:** http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Dialog.html#Gtk.Dialog.run

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

from pprint import pprint

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
    title="Open File"
)

res = dialog.run()

pprint(res)

dialog.destroy()
```

*Note: If you run this, you can exit the GTK gui with <kbd>clt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, it does not exit on normal signals due to example simplicity. You may also end the python process you started from a task manager.*

Versions:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.0
$ python3
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> Gtk._version
'3.0'
```

[image: Example Snippet Screenshot]

Comment: I used your code and [I still get files and folders all over the place](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1214223720448).  I do want to point out that I'm mainly developing this on Windows.  I use linux at home and, admittedly, I don't know if this behaves the same there.  I only tested that the dialog popped up and the file selection worked properly.  The directory I was in only contained files.

Comment: @sdouble On my system the folders are always first in every directory.  Maybe the gtk installation you have was compiled differently (with different flags probably), or that maybe your GTK install's default settings have disabled folder-first. This post mentions the dconf-setting: http://gexperts.com/wp/gnome-3-12-filesnautilus-sort-folders-before-files-issues/ (key org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser and set the option sort-directories-first to true.) But I am unsure how to access dconf on windows, you might try searching for the configuration key name in your gtk install directory. :\

Comment: As this post mentions: http://askubuntu.com/a/549839/250556 dconf settings can be edited with the 'gsettings' binary. Do you have a binary in your gtk install with that name @sdouble?

Comment: @sdouble: Which version of GTK are you using on Windows?

Comment: @Fabby, Gtk 3.0 with Python 3.4.2

Comment: @sdouble: If I'm going to search the source code, I need an exact number: 3.0.0 ... 3.0.9  sorry!  :(

Comment: @Fabby _pkg-config.exe --modversion gtk+-3.0_ reports back 3.6.4

Comment: Maybe I've found something: Do you have a org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml file on your Windows system?

Comment: @Fabby, yes I have one of those files and I found the line for "sort_folders_first" and it is, indeed, set to false.  I was hoping I could get it to work programmatically, without needing to change global settings for Gtk. The demo application that came with Gtk _(gtk-demo.exe - written in C)_ [sorts folders first](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=114226287075), as I would expect to see. Looking at the source for it, it doesn't appear to do anything special, just opens the window. thanks for the help. Searching around, it seems that this is just how Gtk3 works but not sure why their demo works fine

Comment: @sdouble: Shall I convert that into an answer???  (I can add that you can programmatically change that file...)  **:-)**

Comment: @ThorSummoner: As promised in the chat: extra help!  ;)

Comment: @sdouble @Fabby I did a quick Google and pulled up: http://www.micahcarrick.com/gsettings-python-gnome-3.html This might be a lead on setting the gscheema setting for your application. I prefer to respect the global settings, but On windows it basically a FFA anyway. Hope that may help! [P.S. I googled `pygtk set g schema`]